# Getting data from .map file

Tags: c, file, struct

I have a .map file which contain some data from struct that i want. Example of input in the .map file.

àý~ ÷> ÷> 
+.ØæK L÷> C.   ÐB.‘?zlÈ)/@ø>  àý~       ÷> €+/Ü÷> €;-¥ÚkmþÿÿÿÐB.yH.@ø> ƒ  @   €   ÷>

```
struct student {
char *id;
char name[20];
int age;
```

};

```
int main() {
char * buffer;
FILE *fptr;
struct student stud[100];

fptr = fopen("input.map", "wb+");
fread(stud, sizeof(stud), 1, fptr);
for (int i = 0; stud[i].id != NULL; ++i)
{
    printf("Name: %s \n", stud[i].name);
    printf("Age: %s", stud[i].age);
}
fclose(fptr);

system("pause");
```

}

However the output are a bunch of this characters for printing the name...
╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠

for printing the age of the student
-858993460
-858993460
-1533994631
I do not know what went wrong.

Please correct me if i am in the wrong direction. Very new to this language. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't save pointers in a file. A pointer is valid only within a single process.

Comment: You also don't use [`fread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) correctly. You should do e.g. `fread(stud, sizeof(struct student), 100, fptr)`. ***And*** you should check what `fread` *returns* (as well as the `fopen` function of course).

Comment: the [manual for fopen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/) states that "w+" *do write/update: Create an empty file and open it for update (both for input and output). If a **file with the same name already exists its contents are discarded** and the file is treated as a new empty file.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your input doesn't seem to have anything readable in it, I think you must start by validating how you *write* your file.

If you use `fwrite` to output your `struct student`, it will output the direct contents of the memory to file. The pointer `char *` will output as a pointer value (length depends on your system details), the fixed array `char ...[20]` should be output as is, and likewise the integer.

You can output the `char *` string in the file, but be sure to include the zero delimiter that marks the end of string.

Since the length of `char *` contents may vary, you cannot read in the contents using a simple `fread` with a struct. Read the string, and then read field by field according to their type.

Alternatively, you could reorganise your data.

When outputting and inputting binary data, using a simple example files and examining them with a hex editor or hex dump can be very helpful; also including a hex dump of your data instead of a string can advocate more accurate answers.